# Rewrite problem with {QUERY_STRING} and Parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I searched but didn't find a solution for a htaccess rewrite problem I'm facing:

I'm trying to redirect this URL:

```
example.com/search.php?clearSearch=true&searchPhrase=keyword
```

to this URL:

```
example.com/topic/pages/search.php?search=keyword
```

I only want to transfer the "keyword" (words and numbers) to the new URL.

I tested it with many variations but nothing happens:

the normal 301 redirect without keyword runs

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/search.php https://www.example.com/topic/pages/search.php?search=
```

**but this one doesn't runs:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/index.php$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^search.php?clearSearch=true&searchPhrase=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/topic/pages/search.php?search=%1   [R=302,L]
```

What's wrong with my rewrite configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking too complex. Consider this approach instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)searchPhrase=(.*)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule   ^/?index\.php$ /topic/pages/search.php?search=%1   [R=302,QSD,L]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).